# Excel OLAP Set Manager MDX specification

Tags: excel, pivot-table, mdx, olap-cube

I am looking to create a named set in MS Excel (for OLAP pivot table) using MDX that will sum up a subset of quarters within a time dimension for a particular measure.

I have tried the following, all without success. The first one works but just returns the grand total of all the quarters, not the ones I want (first 3 quarters), and it also doesnt include a SUM.

```
{((SUBSET([Period].[Qtr].Members,0,2), [Measures].[Sales]))}

{SUM({SUBSET([Period].[Qtr].Members,0,2)}, [Measures].[Sales])}
```

Why does the second one not work? I have also tried other specifications without subset, like HEAD, Lead(#), and .&[#],  all to no avail. One example is

```
Sum({[Period].[Qtr].Lead(0):[Period].[Qtr].Lead(2)}, [Measures].[Sales])
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly your last example is perfectly good MDX. If you create a Calculated Measure from that, I can see no reason why it would not work.

Here is a working example using the Adventure Works cube, based on your work above:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[SomeMeasure] AS
Sum({[Date].[Calendar Quarter].Lead(0):[Date].[Calendar Quarter].Lead(2)}, [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
SELECT
[Measures].[SomeMeasure] ON COLUMNS
FROM
[Adventure Works]
```

**Edit**

To create a Calculated Measure within your cube, it would look like this:

```
CREATE MEMBER [Measures].[SomeMeasure] AS
Sum({[Date].[Calendar Quarter].Lead(0):[Date].[Calendar Quarter].Lead(2)}, [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
```

This measure will then be available alongside the other measures when using your cube in Excel.
Note: because you are performing a Sum, this is a Calculated Measure. A Named Set is a set of tuples e.g. a set of date members, and I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: Great thank you. For your example, if I am creating a named set with MDX from excel do I need to include the WITH MEMBER, SELECT, FROM, etc? When I create a named set and view the default MDX that is generated it does not contain any of this? Thanks!

Comment: You can create a Calculated Measure within your cube. See my edit for another example.

Comment: @Doug the above answer is not a `named set` it is a calculated member - you can create them also in excel. A named set in excel just needs code like this `{[Date].[Calendar Quarter].Lead(0):[Date].[Calendar Quarter].Lead(2)}`

Comment: I don't think he wants a named set. He wants to perform a sum over a given set of quarters.

Comment: I do want the named set. Although I have realized why it is not working. I am not taking into account the Level(0) 'All' attribute. And so the named set line you reference (and I reference as well) is valid, but it just returns 'All' instead of the Level(1) elements 0:2 like I want it to.